# package -> controller -> route does not work, redirects to home page

Tags: laravel, routes, package, laravel-routing

I created a Laravel package and setup all the things as per Laravel documentation but the issue is that `route` related to `Controller` is not working properly. It redirects to `home` instead of given path in `route`. That `route` is also displayed in `route:list` however, it doesn't work. I don't know why!

package route file:

```
Route::get('calculator', function(){
    echo 'Hello from the package route file package!';
});

Route::get('add/{a}/{b}', 'Devdojo\Calculator\CalculatorController@add');

Route::get('subtract/{a}/{b}', 'Devdojo\Calculator\CalculatorController@subtract');
```

In which `route` `calculator` works fine and it shows correct output where, `add/5/2` and `subtract/5/2` is redirected to home.

`route:list` file
[image]

If you look at above image method add and subtract both register under `auth` as per middleware

CalculatorController:

```
 <?php
namespace Devdojo\Calculator;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CalculatorController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function add($a, $b){
        echo $a + $b;
    }

    public function subtract($a, $b){
        echo $a - $b;
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to see the controller code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. You have a middleware attached to the route which is redirecting to home pages.

```
    Route::get('calculator', function(){
    echo 'Hello from the package route file package!';
});

Route::get('add/{a}/{b}', 'Devdojo\Calculator\CalculatorController@add');

Route::get('subtract/{a}/{b}', 'Devdojo\Calculator\CalculatorController@subtract');
```

Whenever you make changes into your Package you have to do the

`composer dump-autoload`

somehow middleware is getting attached to your controller use the following snippet to remove `middleware`

```
class CalculatorController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function add($a, $b){
        echo $a + $b;
    }

    public function subtract($a, $b){
        echo $a - $b;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: sorry `composer dump-autoload` didn't help me.

Comment: @HirenMangukiya heyy you have middleware on this routes

Comment: it's `auth middelware`, how can i remove that from my `package route`

Comment: in your base controller may you have a middleware

Comment: suppose user add more `middleware` before install package then how could i handle it.

Comment: before use package, user must be a authenticate and answer disabled the authentication on page

Comment: @HirenMangukiya   Yess user must be logged in to access these routes

Comment: but it executes even user was not authenticated